# Setup method with FindOptions<T> as parameter in UnitTest using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mongodb-.net-driver

Imagine I have this class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<MyOtherClass> MyOtherClassList { get; set; }
}
```

And this method on my service layer which I want to unit-test with [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4) and [xunit](http://xunit.github.io/):

```
public IList<MyClass> GetAll()
{
    var options = new FindOptions<MyClass>
    {
        Projection = Builders<MyClass>.Projection
            .Exclude(m => m.MyOtherClassList)
    };

    return MyClassRepository.GetAll(options)
}
```

And this would be the test:

```
[Fact]
public void GetAll_Success()
{
    //Arrange
    List<MyClass> expected = ... ;

    var mockMyClassRepository = new Mock<IMyClassRepository>();
    mockMyClassRepository.Setup(m => m.GetAll(It.IsAny<FindOptions<MyClass>>())).Returns(expected); 

    var myClassService = new MyClassService(mockMyClassRepository);

    //Act
    var result = myClassService.GetAll();

    //Assert
    Assert.Equal(expected, result);
    mockMyClassRepository.Verify(m => m.GetAll(It.IsAny<FindOptions<MyClass>>()), Times.Once);
}
```

I want to avoid using It.IsAny for the FindOptions and be sure that the findOptions are excluding the MyOtherClassList attribute but I'm not sure how to compare the FindOptions class.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you seriously going to unit-test your DAL using mocking instead of a test DB?

Comment: @DannyVarod That's a very common approach, FYI

Comment: Well, I'm taking this approach, but it would be really helpful if you can share any article with more information on why it's better to use a test DB.

Comment: And actually here I'm testing the service layer, not the DAL.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto there are many common mistakes.

Comment: @DannyVarod I didn't say it was a good approach ;)

Comment: @joacoleza then you are mocking too low, you should be mocking the interface the DAL provides.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto how can you answer that fast!?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expression in the Returns to inspect the provided argument so you can apply what ever filtering you want.

```
mockMyClassRepository
    .Setup(_ => _.GetAll(It.IsAny<FindOptions<MyClass>>()))
    .Returns((FindOptions<MyClass> options) => {
        var projection = options.Projection;
        //...use as desired to filter the expected.
        return expected;
    });
```

The same could have been done in a `Callback` where the `expected` could be manipulated/altered, again based on the passed argument.

Do note that what ever is done with the passed argument is an implementation concern that applies to what is done by the actual repository, which you are trying to mock.

The only way to be sure that the `findOptions` are actually excluding the `MyOtherClassList` attribute would be via an integration test.

Answer (score 0):

Hows this

```
mockMyClassRepository
.Setup(m => m.GetAll(It.IsAny<FindOptions<MyClass>>()))
.Returns(FindOptions<MyClass> a) =>
{
    if (a.MyOtherClass != null || a.MyOtherClass.Length() > 0)
       throw new InvalidOperationException();
    else
       return expected;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to be more specific on the `.Verify` call, you can leave the `.Setup` call to use `It.IsAny`, then use additional constrains on the verify call, like this:

```
mockMyClassRepository.Verify(m => m.GetAll(It.Is<FindOptions<MyClass>>(options => 
                          options.Projection == .... //whatever logic would return true for your success criteria
                            )), Times.Once);
```